# Php Prepared Statement Returning 0 in Binded Variables, SQL Statement works fine in DB

Tags: php, mysql, variables

```
        // Load Filters
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
        SELECT 
        display_showCancelled,
        display_showCompleted,
        display_showNotPossible
        FROM `ticketing_settings`
        WHERE user = ?
        "); 
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['userID']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($displayCancelled, $displayCompleted, $displayNotPossible);
```

If I run the query in the db, its working fine, but somehow the values dont bind to the vars... its returning "0" instead of "1" any ideas?

Right after this stmt im running

```
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
        ticketing_tickets.id, 
        ticketing_tickets.description,
        ticketing_type.responsible,
        ticketing_tickets.date_created,
        users.firstname,
        users.lastname,
        ticketing_type.name,
        ticketing_tickets.status,
        ticketing_status.name
        FROM `ticketing_tickets`
        LEFT JOIN ticketing_status ON ticketing_tickets.status = ticketing_status.id
        LEFT JOIN ticketing_type ON ticketing_tickets.type = ticketing_type.id
        LEFT JOIN users ON ticketing_tickets.creator = users.id
        WHERE ticketing_tickets.status NOT LIKE ?
        AND ticketing_tickets.status NOT LIKE ?
        AND ticketing_tickets.status NOT LIKE ?
        AND ticketing_tickets.status NOT LIKE ?
        ");
        $ticketStatusReq = 1;
        $stmt->bind_param('iiii', $ticketStatusReq, $displayCancelled, $displayCompleted, $displayNotPossible); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($ticketId, $ticketDescription, $ticketResponsible, $ticketDate, $ticketFirstname, $ticketLastname, $ticketTypeName, $ticketStatus, $ticketStatusName);
```

which works completely fine.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION['userID']);` show you?  P.S. Did you call `session_start();`?

Comment: Already double checked the session vars, have multiple statements running and using those vars and everywhere it works fine except this statement...

P.S. I replaced the session var with a fixed int to check if there is sth wrong. But same result.

Comment: is the userid session var an integer?

Comment: Yes, using same var in different queries and all good, so the issue is really not on this part of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hahah omg, cant believe how stupid this issue was, just forgot to fetch... so sorry haha but sometimes being lost in thousands of lines of code you dont notice the most obvious issues...

Comment: Thanks!  I made the same exact mistake!!

Comment: Except I had that issue with bind_result.